# If I only need 1 UITableViewCell, can I create it without using a reuse identifier and all that stuff?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios5, ios6

In the cellAtIndexPath method, could I just do something like:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
UILabel *label = // make label
[cell addSubview:label];

return cell;
```

Is that possible, or something similar?

Comment: Why want you to get rid of Apple programming practices and guidelines?

Comment: @Malloc I've done this many times when I just want a one or two row table view fast. It's a totally valid question.

Comment: @user212541 Remember to mark my answer as correct if it helped you. (Little green checky marky thing) Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sure, that code will work for your situation**.

It would also work for a 10,000 row table view, but you would sacrifice the performance enhancements that the table view uses, like cell reuse. Using a 10k cell TV without caching would result in an unusable experience.

Comment: It's worth noting that 10000 cells without caching (that's what the identifier is used for) would result in an unusable tableview.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Noted.

Answer (score 1):

It's a valid question, but iOS use the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` in order to better manage the displayed rows in case your table view has rows that exceeds the frame of the screen. So this is totally not recommended practice. As far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

If your table view has only one or two rows, maybe you'd probably be better served just not using a table view, unless it is providing a crucial piece of functionality. If you have more than, say 4 or 5 instances of a cell you'll want to incorporate re-use so that you are not creating a new cell for every instance of a cell in the table. You can imagine that would eat up your memory pretty quickly.

Comment: A single cell eats up practically zero mem